# Detect single or multiple file drag

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I built a file upload allowing drag-n-drop.
I can detect when a file is being dragged over the draggable element, my problem is:
is it possible once i detect a file being dragged over the element - if its 1 file or multiple files?
(i want to allow single file uploads only - without allowing the user to drop multiple files).

Thanks a lot for the help,

Good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've used jQuery to register the `drop` handler then the detail is in the `ev.originalEvent` property:

```
function drop(ev) {
    int n = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length;
}
```

However this won't be available until the files are actually dropped - the `dragenter` event doesn't populate that property.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
  addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
    // store the ID of the element, and collect it on the drop later on
    event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
  });
```